# How to extend JoinClause class in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-7, laravel-5.7

We would like to extend the JoinClause class which Query\Builder uses to formulate join clauses.

We already extend the BaseModel's query builder like so: (In essence, CoreBaseModel is just a model with some extra functions.)

```
abstract class BaseModel extends CoreBaseModel
{
    function newBaseQueryBuilder()
    {
        return new BaseModelQueryBuilder($this->getConnection());
    }
}
```

Example code in BaseModelQueryBuilder:

```
class BaseModelQueryBuilder extends Builder
{
    function findOverlapping($from, $till, $from_column, $till_column)
    {
        return $this
            ->orWhereBetween($from_column, [$from, $till])
            ->orWhereBetween($till_column, [$from, $till])
            ->orWhere(function($query) use($from_column, $till_column, $from, $till)
            {
                //Around
                $query
                    ->where($from_column, '<=' , $from)
                    ->where($till_column, '>=', $till);
            });
    }
}
```

This is nice, because you can then use the function findOverlapping, not only in every query, but also every subquery, on that model.

The problem is that this doesn't work for the advanced join clauses:

```
BaseModel::join('table_name', function($join)
{
    $join->where(function($query)
    {
        $query->findOverlapping('2018-01-01', '2018-21-31', 'from', 'till');
    });
});
```

The error is:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::findOverlapping()
```

So I've been digging around to try and find a solution to this problem, and found the join function on the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` that looks like this:

```
/**
 * Add a join clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $table
 * @param  \Closure|string  $first
 * @param  string|null  $operator
 * @param  string|null  $second
 * @param  string  $type
 * @param  bool    $where
 * @return $this
 */
public function join($table, $first, $operator = null, $second = null, $type = 'inner', $where = false)
{
    $join = new JoinClause($this, $type, $table);

    // If the first "column" of the join is really a Closure instance the developer
    // is trying to build a join with a complex "on" clause containing more than
    // one condition, so we'll add the join and call a Closure with the query.
    if ($first instanceof \Closure) {
        call_user_func($first, $join);

        $this->joins[] = $join;

        $this->addBinding($join->getBindings(), 'join');
    }

    // If the column is simply a string, we can assume the join simply has a basic
    // "on" clause with a single condition. So we will just build the join with
    // this simple join clauses attached to it. There is not a join callback.
    else {
        $method = $where ? 'where' : 'on';

        $this->joins[] = $join->$method($first, $operator, $second);

        $this->addBinding($join->getBindings(), 'join');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So I copied the function to the `BaseModelQueryBuilder`, made a copy of the `Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause` class, and assigned it to the overriding join function's first statement: 
`$join = new BaseModelJoinClause($this, $type, $table)`

Please note that I did not change any code in the `BaseModelJoinClause` class compared to the original `JoinClause` class( except from `use` statements and the namespace ofc). Still, even with this subtle change( only assigned new class which is an exact copy of the original) all queries start to fail with errors like: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax`.

If anyone got some tips on how to resolve this issue, or has any experience extending the JoinClause class on laravel, any help is welcome :) If you think you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: The latest release 5.7.20 adds a `Builder::newJoinClause()` method to simplify extending the `JoinClause` class: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26948

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, good to see that the laravel developers take care of these things :)